# Run both AWS and Wasabi CLI on the same Mac Computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, wasabi

I’ve created a bash script to upload files to AWS S3 using the CLI. I would now like to add some redundancy to my backup routine and would like send some of the files to Wasabi using the CLI.  I have not been able to find an article addressing weather this is possible and if so how to configure Wasabi with the configure command.  Would someone please answer the following:

Is it possible?

If so, how do you use the Wasabi configure command without interfering with the AWS configure command?

Any help would be appreciated,

John

I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: What is the specific problem? Doesn't Wasabi also use the AWS CLI? You could just define a separate `--profile` for your Wasabi credentials. See: [How do I use AWS CLI with Wasabi? – Wasabi Knowledge Base](https://knowledgebase.wasabi.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001910791-How-do-I-use-AWS-CLI-with-Wasabi)

Comment: So I could just do: aws configure --profile wasabi, correct?  Do I have to create a new profile for S3 or is it still just AWS configure ? Thank you

Comment: If you do not specify `--profile`, then the configuration is stored in the `default` profile. So, probably best to _always_ specify a profile so you know which credentials you are using. You can store the configuration with `aws configure --profile <something>` and use it with, for example, `aws s3 ls --profile <something>`

Comment: One more question please, what is the commend to upload the one file contained in the "/Users/thor/S3Test/" directory to the "awscliw" bucket in the usa-east-1 region?

Thank you

Comment: You would use `aws s3 cp /Users/thor/S3Test/filename s3://awscliw/` -- which assumes you know the `filename`. If you want to  copy ALL files in that source directory, use: `aws s3 cp --recursive /Users/thor/S3Test/ s3://awscliw/`

Comment: I was missing the cp   Thank you

Comment: What would the command  be to upload the same file to Wasabi, USA-East-1 , “wtest” bucket? Thank you

Comment: You would need to configure Wasabi credentials and endpoint in a profile. Then, you would use the same command but refer to that profile.